# Using awk to remove lines containing a string in two columns of line

Tags: awk, sed

I have my input like this:

```
gi|88193823|ref|NC_007795.1|:3070-3370 gi|387601291|ref|NC_017333.1|:297226-297526 0.361403508772
gi|387601291|ref|NC_017333.1|:216167-216467 gi|88193823|ref|NC_007795.1|:2735510-2735810 0.386440677966
gi|88193823|ref|NC_007795.1|:1278679-1278979 gi|88193823|ref|NC_007795.1|:2735510-2735810 0.392491467577
```

I want output by removing the line containing `007795` in both column 1 and 2.

Expected output:

```
gi|88193823|ref|NC_007795.1|:3070-3370 gi|387601291|ref|NC_017333.1|:297226-297526 0.361403508772
gi|387601291|ref|NC_017333.1|:216167-216467 gi|88193823|ref|NC_007795.1|:2735510-2735810 0.386440677966
```

I tried

```
awk '! ( $1 == "/007795/" && $2 == "/007795/" )' 1.txt > 1.temp
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help me

Comment: I don't see `007795` in first or second column in any of the records.

Comment: @JamesBrown It seems delimiter is space, not `|`...

Comment: Oh yeah, there seems to be some space there. Pretty obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the double quotes, since you are using the slashes to delimit the regex literal, and you need to use a regex match instead of an equality comparison, since you want to test if the fields contain the string. The command should look like this:

```
awk '! ( $1 ~ /007795/ && $2 ~ /007795/ )' file
```

Comment: kindly I'm using this on ubuntu as windows 10 linux subsystem. I awk one CSV file , on the terminal at the end of the process ONLY rows matching the regex are displayed BUT the file remains the same and rows are not removed cut, any kind hint? I tried to rename the file and it does rename so I have write rights. Thank you

Comment: @Robert: 99% of the time that awk is producing unexpected results on windows is CRLF problems, try `does2unix file` before anything else.

Comment: good tip, but, weird I have tried cat in combination with grep and it works though I had obviously to output to a different file